# Pong Paddle Movement Issues

Tags: java, pong

I'm working on a Pong game for my portfolio right now in Java, and I'm just having a slight problem with the Pong paddle movement. Obviously, I don't want the paddles moving off-screen, so I'm trying to make it so when it reaches a certain point on its Y-axis, it will not move any farther. I've gotten it to work for the top of the screen, but not the bottom, and I can't figure out why. The conditional I'm using SHOULD work, but it will just move right off the bottom of the screen if I go far enough. Here's the conditionals for each paddle's movement. If you need more of my code, just ask.

```
// Check for Left Paddle movement.
if( ( wKey ) && ( paddle_left.getY() >= ( paddle_speed * 2 ) ) )
    paddle_left.setY( paddle_left.getY() - paddle_speed ); 
else if( ( sKey ) && ( paddle_left.getY() <= ( boardHeight - 10 ) ) )
    paddle_left.setY( paddle_left.getY() + paddle_speed );

// Check for Right Paddle movement
if( ( upKey ) && ( paddle_right.getY() >= ( paddle_speed * 2 ) ) )
    paddle_right.setY( paddle_right.getY() - paddle_speed );
else if( ( downKey ) && ( paddle_right.getY() <= ( boardHeight - 10 ) ) )
    paddle_right.setY( paddle_right.getY() + paddle_speed );
```

The variable `paddle_speed` is a constant equal to 5. Also, `boardHeight` is the height of the screen on which everything is drawn, which is equal to 480.

Also, this isn't as important, but I've noticed a slight delay from when I start to hold down the key to when the paddle starts moving. I know it's because of the initial key press delay set on the user's computer, but how can I compensate for this?

EDIT:
Ok, I changed my code to reflect your answer and I've got this now:

```
// Check for Left Paddle movement.
if( ( wKey ) && ( paddle_left.getY() >= ( paddle_speed * 2 ) ) ) paddle_left.setY( paddle_left.getY() - paddle_speed );
else if( ( sKey ) && ( paddle_left.getY() <= ( boardHeight - ((paddle_speed * 2) + paddleHeight) ) ) ) paddle_left.setY( paddle_left.getY() + paddle_speed );

// Check for Right Paddle movement.
if( ( upKey ) && ( paddle_right.getY() >= ( paddle_speed * 2 ) ) ) paddle_right.setY( paddle_right.getY() - paddle_speed );
else if( ( downKey ) && ( paddle_right.getY() <= ( boardHeight - ((paddle_speed * 2) + paddleHeight) ) ) ) paddle_right.setY( paddle_right.getY() + paddle_speed );
```

However, it still goes a little below screen. It does stop now, but it goes maybe 20 pixels beyond the screen still. I don't get it. I even used Paint and drew the coordinates and simulated how the logic should work, and it should stop 5 pixels from the edge of the bottom of the screen. Can you figure out why it's not?

Comment: Regarding your second code change, is the paddle X & Y coords the top left corner of the paddle? Also, what is the value paddleHeight?

Comment: Yes, the origin point of the paddle (rectangle) is the top-left corner. Also, the paddleHeight variable is 100.

Comment: In a test app I also get the paddle stopping 5 pixels from the bottom. Might the problem be somewhere else in your code perhaps?

Comment: I can't see where... let me commit the project to Github and I'll post a link to it.

Comment: Here's the GitHub project page: https://github.com/packetpirate/Pong

Comment: It's because you set the frame size (which includes the title bar and frame border) instead of the size of your board panel. In your main method do `board.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(768,480));` then add the board to the frame then call `frame.pack();`. Remove the line that sets the frame size. PS Please vote for my answer and comments if they help ^^

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. Now to work on the delay problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you don't take the size of your paddle into account when checking for the bottom of the screen. So if your paddle is bigger than your speed size (5) then it will be draw below the bottom of the screen.

For the key repeat delay problem you will probably have to keep flags for which keys are down. Set the flags on keyPressed() events and clear it on keyReleased() and then update the paddles using a timer.

Comment: Holy crap, I feel like an idiot... thank you.

Also, I do have flags set for the keys for the keyPressed and keyReleased events. I'll look up timers and see if I can get that part down. Any suggestions for where I should start?

Comment: Glad to help :) The timer depends on how you are drawing your paddles, but you can look at [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) as a start.